# How to open a child window and that time parent window should be disable

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to show a child window which will perform some action and it will set to the parent window. The time when child window is open , parent window should be disable.
I tried this which return child window but parent window still in working mode while child window is open...

```
<a href="AddChoice" onclick="var x = window.open('url',,'','hemenubar=yes,height= 300,       
width = 500,,scrollbars=no,dialog=yes,minimize=no,maximize=no, 
alwaystop=yes,copyhistory= no,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,directories=no
,location=no,menubar=no,status=no,left=0,top=0');return false;">
Change Dependent Question...</a>
//This link returns a child window
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a modal dialog box. there are many ways to do that.
you can use some existing plug-ins.

jquery: http://www.designlabelblog.com/2009/03/20-ways-to-create-javascript-modal.html

YUI: http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/panel/panel-form.html

Comment: I did.. But modal dialog box does not return value in Chrome and FireFox.

Comment: Is n't any option that we can do the same with window.open() function??